# Python find fields from text Files

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

Pretty simple python 2.7 find/replace text question - I have text files which are all one long line each (no newline characters), and inside each long line are comma-separated sections like so (although there are portions which are not of this format):

`"Country":"USA","City":"Chicago","Phone":"123-456-7890","Contact":"John Doe"`

I want to go thru the text files and whenever a `':'` character is found for one of a couple fields I'm looking for, print out the field and corresponding value (which are always in quotes) with a delimiter between them...so let's say I'm looking just for the `'Country'` and `'City'` fields - I'd want to find either of those field names in quotes and print out the corresponding values like so:

`Country|USA`
`City|Chicago`

while ignoring all other `':'` paired values.

Comment: Please post your code to approach this problem statment..

Comment: tips: you should post some code of you trying this before posting on SO since this site is mostly for debugging, not making code for others.

Comment: This looks like a job for the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = {x.split(':')[0].replace('"', '').lower().strip(): x.split(':')[1].replace('"', '').strip() for x in f.read().split(',')}

user_in = raw_input('Search: ')
print '{0}|{1}'.format(user_in, data.get(user_in.lower(), 'Not Found'))
```

Comment: getting 'IndexError: list index out of range' error on this

Answer (score 0):

```
st = '"Country":"USA","City":"Chicago","Phone":"123-456-7890","Contact":"John Doe"'

def get_value(string_,key_):
    d = {}
    st2 = string_.split(",")

    for el in st2:
        k,v = el.split(":")
        k = k[1:-1]
        d[k] = v

    return d[key_][1:-1]


print(get_value(st, "Country") )
# USA

keywords  = ["Country","City", "Phone", "Contact"]

for w in keywords:
    print(get_value(st, w))

USA
Chicago
123-456-7890
John Doe
```